# WCF ServiceBehavoir.InstanceContextMode in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, azure, instancecontextmode

Does anyone know how the WCF `ServiceBehavoir.InstanceContexMode` is affected when hosting the WCF service in Azure?

A service that is configured for `PerCall` instancing, and handles multiple concurrent requests on-prem, does not seem to process more than 2 concurrent requests when hosted in Azure. Are there other settings that will throttle the requests?

Comment: How exactly are you hosting the WCF service in Azure? Web site? Web role? VM + IIS or self-host?

Comment: WebRole - however, I have an update...  It appears that the limitation was due to client-side testing issues - restrictions on concurrent outbound http connections from the same machine, and not server side settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** It appears that the limitation was due to client-side testing issues - restrictions on concurrent outbound http connections from the same machine, and not server side settings.

Being new to Azure, I had mistakenly thought that Azure's instancing and scaling options might be overriding what I had configured in WCF ServiceBehavoir, but this was a red herring.

The client-side restrictions were increased by altering the following registry entry on the client PC used for testing...

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
```

Once I had done this, I was able to test multiple concurrent connections to my Cloud Service from the same client PC, and with only a single 'instance' running in Azure.